# Vaadin 23 PageNotFound route returns 200ok instead of 404

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

This is my custom `PageNotFound` route:

```
@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class PageNotFound extends RouteNotFoundError {

    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event, ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
        VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

        // some logic

        getElement().insertChild(0, verticalLayout.getElement());

        return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    }

}
```

Despite the fact I return `HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND` the page still returns 200ok instead of 404. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Known limitation. https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13421

Comment: Thanks, is it safe to use `vaadin.eagerServerLoad=true` as a workaround for this issue with Vaadin Flow 23 ?

Comment: I would not recommend it personally.

Comment: Are there any other ways to return the correct code? The problem - to improve the SEO of my Vaadin Flow application, I connected prerender.io. Without the correct 404 code, prerender.io will render and cache tons of the false-present pages...

Comment: Handle it before the request hits Vaadin, for example in Spring Boot.